# Why did the game shout DELETE IMMEDIATELY at me?

Tags: needy-streamer-overload

Sometime around Day 20 of Needy Streamer Overload, the screen went dark and displayed "DELETE IMMEDIATELY" on the screen multiple times. I then got screaming texts from Ame before the game reset itself.

Why did the game start shouting "DELETE IMMEDIATELY"?

[image: DELETE IMMEDIATELY repeated several times]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> When Ame's mental darkness reaches 100% and she takes a Magic Grass, there is a very low chance that the screen will distort VERY rapidly, followed by the text "DELETE IMMEDIATELY" flooding it and the game kicking you back to the title screen.

[Source](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/NightmareFuel/NeedyStreamerOverload).

---

As pointed out by Wondercricket, I missed a sub-note:

> The text is actually a Shout-Out to a popular Urban Legend about Shin Megami Tensei, where the game might suddenly freeze on boot and display the message "すぐにけせ"

<sub>(すぐにけせ means "shut-down (消す) immediately (すぐに)")</sub>

Comment: すぐにけせ means more like "close (the game) immediately", or "shut your console down"

Comment: @Skye-AT which makes more sense

Comment: That is one obscure easter egg lol

Comment: This reminds me of "Raiden, turn the game console off right now!"

Comment: Could also be a reference to the 2005 Weird Al song "Virus Alert" - The chorus contains the line *"Delete immediately before someone gets hurt"*.